# Formatting Dates in QGIS labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to display a date field as a label. The data is from a shapefile. The field in question is a date field.

When I use the date field for the label, it displays in the yyyy/mm/dd format. I would like to get it to the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Is this possible. I know in MapInfo I would use the FormatDate function, I wondered whether something similar existed in QGIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Expressions now support date formatting, for example

```
format_date('2012-05-15','dd.MM.yyyy') → '15.05.2012'
```

---

Currently, there is work going on related to "expression based labeling": http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3488.

For now, you can use Field Calculator to convert your datetime string to a different format, e.g. YYYY/MM/DD to DD.MM.YYYY like this:

```
substr(date,8,2)||'.'||substr(date,5,2)||'.'||substr(date,0,4)
```

Substring syntax is:

```
substr(string,startpos,length)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can open the shape.dbf file in your favorite spreadsheet editor:

- Create a new column, call it `temp_date`.
- Copy and pate the old date data to temp_date
- Split that column using `text to data` feature by character `\` or whichever happens to be your date splitter
- Reorganize the columns in the order you want
- Create a new column `new_date`
- In new_date use the following formula `=A1 & "/" & B1 & "/" & C1`. Of course you need to use the proper fields and not the ones I mentioned.

Of course there could be a default way for QGis to handle date formats, but I haven't seen it. Perhaps, play around wit the field calculator if that helps at all

I'm sure there is an option to do it using the qgis python console, I don't suspect this will be a big deal either using the time /time date modules or just a generic str.replace or reg expression. I'm not verse with the api so I can't help there

Comment: It is not a good idea to edit dbf outside of a GIS program because the ObjectID field will not carry over into excel. http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=302104

Comment: @artwork21 - Thanks, I will delete my answer shortly.

Comment: The thread referenced by @artwork21 documents a fundamental user error: when you *sort* the dbf, you destroy the connection between it and the features.  (OID is a complete red herring; it's not used in the shapefile structure.)  Provided you don't insert rows, delete rows, or reorder rows when editing the .dbf file, you'll be ok.  Consider re-opening your reply in light of this.